# find value in a string of cell considering some margin

Tags: matlab, find, cell-array, binning

Suppose that I have a string of values corresponding to the height of a group of people

```
height_str ={'1.76000000000000';
'1.55000000000000';
'1.61000000000000';
'1.71000000000000';
'1.74000000000000';
'1.79000000000000';
'1.74000000000000';
'1.86000000000000';
'1.72000000000000';
'1.82000000000000';
'1.72000000000000';
'1.63000000000000'}
```

and a single height value.

```
height_val = 177;
```

I would like to find the indices of the people that are in the range `height_val` +- 3cm.

To find the exact match I would do like this

[`idx_height,~]=find(ismember(cell2mat(height_str),height_val/100));`

How can I include the matches in the previous range (174-180)?

`idx_height` should be = `[1 5 6 7]`

Comment: Why not use a numeric array instead of that cell array?

Comment: @Divakar data are given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the precision of heights stays at `0.01cm`, you can use a combination of `str2double` and `ismember` for a one-liner -

```
idx_height = find(ismember(str2double(height_str)*100,[height_val-3:height_val+3]))
```

- The magic with `str2double` is that it works directly with cell arrays to get us a numeric array without resorting to a combined effort of converting that cell array to a char array and then to a numeric array.
- After the use of `str2double`, we can use `ismember` as you tried in your problem to get us the matches as a logical array, whose indices are picked up with `find`. That's the whole story really.

Comment: Maybe `str2doule` ain't so bad after all.  ;)

Comment: @chappjc It's a straight route to have numeric data, for cases like these. It's perfect! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert you strings into an numeric array (as @Divakar mentioned) by

```
height = str2num(char(height_str))*100; % in cm
```

Then just

```
idx_height = find(height>=height_val-3 & height<=height_val+3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Late addition, but for binning my first choice would be to go with `bsxfun` and logical operations:

```
idx_height = find(bsxfun(@le,str2double(height_str)*100,height_val+3) & ...
    bsxfun(@ge,str2double(height_str)*100,height_val-3))
```